# yii2 - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048

Tags: php, yii2

I'm new to yii2, I'm trying to send a request to the database, but it comes out that such columns cannot be null, although when checking through @var_dump I can see the sending data, what is the matter and how to fix it

---> Controller

```
 public function actionSignup()
{
    $model = new Signup();

    if (isset($_POST['Signup'])) {
        $model->attributes = Yii::$app->request->post('Signup');


        if ($model->validate()) {
            $model->signup();
            # code...
        }
    }

    return $this->render('signup', ['model'=>$model]);
```

---> View page

```
<?php
use \yii\widgets\ActiveForm; 
?>
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['class'=>'form-horizontal']);
?>

<?= $form->field($model,'email')->textInput(['autofocus'=>true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model,'password')->passwordInput() ?>

<div>
<button type="submit" class="btn primary-btn">Submit</button>
</div>
<?php
ActiveForm::end();
?>
```

---> Model

```
class Signup extends Model
{
public $email;
public $password;

public function reles()
{
    return [

        [['email', 'password'], 'required'],
        ['email', 'email'],
        ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass'=>'app\models\User'],
        ['password', 'string', 'min'=>2,'max'=>10]
    ];
}

public function signup()
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->email = $this->email;
    $user->password = $this->password;
    return $user->save();
}
```

---> phpmyadmin database

[image]

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;


class User extends ActiveRecord
{

}
```

--> var_dump [image]

--> sql [image][image]
[image]

Comment: Show your table structure and `Yii::$app->request->post('Signup')` content

Comment: Added a question

Comment: 1. Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE users` in database and copy `Create Table` content to this question. 2. Do `var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post('Signup'))` and copy content to this question

Comment: ---> var_dump array(2) { ["email"]=> string(4) "test" ["password"]=> string(4) "test" } ;;;

phpmyadmin -> user -> sql -> SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE 1

Comment: @Justinas Okey, i did and include in question

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
**
     * Signs user up.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionSignup()
    {

        $model = new SignupForm()
        //Sign up if it is post request
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->signup()) { //Here YOU LOAD your POST data in to the Lodal using load() method.
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Thank you for registration. Please check your email for further instructions.', false);
            return $this->goHome();
        } else {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Sorry, you can not register right now.', false);
            return $this->redirect('/login');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

### In Model

First of all, the *method* for ***attribute rules*** is called "**rules**" I don't know if it's a typo from you in the question *or* this is the problem; If there are no rules for user input data the returned values will be ***NULL***, I have faced this issue before, I didn't include a *rules()* method (or in your case it's name is not correct) and the model returned null for attribute values. Your code have to be:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [

        [['email', 'password'], 'required'],
        ['email', 'email'],
        ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass'=>'app\models\User'],
        ['password', 'string', 'min'=>2,'max'=>10]
    ];
}
```

Technical note: normally, or based upon my understanding a password should have a minimum of *8* not *2* characters, if the password entered is only 2 characters it can be brute-forced in a second.

### In Controller

As in @Serghei Leonenco's Answer, Yii2 already provides some functions to use to handle *post* requests and so, so please stick to Yii2 functions it can enhance your app security

So in the actionSignup() method the code ought to be

```
public function actionSignup()
{
    $model = new Signup();

    // Loads the post request directly onto the model and validates it against the model rules() method
    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate){
            $model->signup();      
            // Model validated and saved successfully, IT OUGHT TO BE SAVED IN THE DATABASE AT THIS POINT
            // Here you can set a flash or redirect the user to another page  
    }

    return $this->render('signup', ['model'=>$model]);
}
```

### In View

At last, in your view code it's better to use Yii2 internal functions for Html buttons

```
<?= Html::submitButton('Signup', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

Of course don't forget to *use* *yii\helpers\Html*

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
```